# Lucene searching numerical

Tags: lucene.net, lucene

I have a strange issue with lucene.net 2.9: 
If I searching for: `high-quality` it doesn't find any results. I found hyphenation char (-) is a problem for Lucene, so I search for `high quality` and it worked perfectly.

When I search for `30-40` it is showing results but for `30 40` is not showing any.

The second scenarios is in contradiction with first one. 
I guess the second one is related as I have numerical text, but I didn't find something on web related.

Comment: Can you be slighty more specific to what exactly you are doing. How are you invoking lucene? What data type is used and so fourth.

Comment: I have some pdf that are indexing. I checked with Luke, and when I search with Luke I have same problem, if text I'm searching contains "minus character" are not found and if text contains number followed by minus and after followed by number again is found.  1) high-quality is not found; 2) high quality is found; 3) 30-40 is found; 4) 30 40 is not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you are using `StandardAnalyzer` when indexing your terms, and then are searching without analysis in some form, or with a different form of analysis.

The 2.9 `StandardAnalyzer` (`ClassicAnalyzer`, as of version 3.1) has some interesting behavior around hyphens.  To quote the [`StandardTokenizer` documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardTokenizer.html):

> Splits words at hyphens, unless there's a number in the token, in which case the whole token is interpreted as a product number and is not split.

So, two hyphenated words (or any collection of letters) will be split into separate tokens, when any number thrown into the mix will interpret the whole thing as a product number, and index as a ingle token, hyphens and all, so:

- "high-qualtiy" --> "high" and "quality"
- "ab-cd" ---------> "ab" and "cd"
- "30-40" ---------> "30-40"
- "ab-c4" ---------> "ab-c4"
- "30 40" ---------> "30" and "40"

So, if you construct a `TermQuery` for "high-quality" on such an analyzed field, you will get no results (though you would if using the `QueryParser` with the same analyzer).  When searching for "30-40", the `TermQuery` for "30-40" will be an exact match. but matches will be found for neither "30" nor "40".

So, I'm not how you are querying to run into the mismatch there (perhaps using `StandardAnalyzer` when indexing, and `WhitespaceAnalyzer` when querying?), but hopefully that points in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

You need to encrypt "-" sign to URL parameter. I think it will works fine.